# Is there a more elegant way to write the following Coq code?

Tags: coq

```
match x with
| Some x => Some (Ref x)
| None => None
end.
```

I have to do this quite a lot, nested matches make code look bad. Is there some more elegant, one liner sort of way to lift things out of Option?

Comment: In the ssreflect plugin you have `omap Ref x` from ssrfun.

Answer (score 6):

There is `option_map` function in [`Coq.Init.Datatypes`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Init.Datatypes.html#option_map) defined as follows:

```
Definition option_map (A B:Type) (f:A->B) (o : option A) : option B :=
  match o with
    | Some a => @Some B (f a)
    | None => @None B
  end.
```

You can use it just like @ejgallego showed in the comments: `option_map Ref x`.

Here is how you can discover this function:

```
Search (option _ -> option _).
```

Answer (score 5):

More generally, you may want to consider using monadic syntax; it is easy to define some yourself with a couple of Notation declarations, or you can use a more featureful library like Gregory Malecha's ExtLib.